# Affine schemes which are also projective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, projective-schemes

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra, with $k$ a field. I know (and have also seen it at this site) that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is $k$-isomorphic to a Proj-scheme $\mathrm{Proj}(B) \mapsto \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ for some graded commutative ring $B$. 
How does $B$ look like ?

What about if $A$ is a finitely generated $C$-algebra, with $C$ a commutative ring ?

Comment: How about $A[T]$?

Comment: @A. Rod: Oeps, I forgot the more general setting -- will add it to the question.

Comment: Do you have a source for your first claim? If spec(A) is isomorphic to Proj(B), and say B is a graded ring with B_0 = k and B is finitely generated as a B_0-algebra (eg if B is noetherian), then Proj(B) is proper over spec(k), but any proper morphism of affine varieties is finite, so that implies that A must be a finite dim k-vector space (alternatively argue on global sections).

So if the claim were to be true, then B wouldn't be of the form above at least...

Comment: @user37864: What do you mean with "B wouldn't be of the form above" ?

Comment: The assumption is that $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, so $\text{Spec}(A)$ is definitely proper over $k$.

Comment: I interpreted the first claim in OP as saying that for every f.g. k-algebra $A$, $\mathrm{Spec} A$ is isomorphic to some $\mathrm{Proj} B$ which I am inclined to believe is false (although I'm not sure how to justify this completely)... If $B$ is of the form I mentioned in the previous comment, then we have $\mathrm{Proj} B$ is proper over $k$, hence $\mathrm{Spec} A$ is proper over $k$, which implies that $\mathrm{Spec A} \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} k$ is finite. It's possible that  I misinterpreted OP though.